# is it possible to play youtube videos on android in a custom app on the background?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, android-youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am working on a playlist app that must play for long periods in the background.
But since the youtube app does not allow playing videos in the background I wonder if the API allows this

Answer (score 0):

No, the API does not allow this. Check out the [terms of service](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms) - there's a bit under Prohibitions that's relevant to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I got error when tried to do so : Its not permitted

YouTube video playback stopped due to unauthorized overlay on top of player. The YouTubePlayerView is obscured by android.widget.RelativeLayout{10146fc3 V.E..... ......I. 0,0-720,1052 #7f080001 app:id/slide_down_view}. YouTubePlayerView is completely covered, with the distance in px between each edge of the obscuring view and the YouTubePlayerView being: left: 0, top: 647, right: 0, bottom: 0..